# Why is it not displaying my button?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, button

I am trying to use a layered pane to make a menu for a program I'm working on, but the button won't display. I can't seem to figure out what it is...

```
public class FlashcardGUI {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    JFrame projectFrame = new JFrame("StudyFast Flashcard");
    projectFrame.setName("StudyFast Flashcards");
    projectFrame.setSize(1000,600);
    projectFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    projectFrame.setVisible(true);


    JLayeredPane projectLayeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
    projectFrame.setContentPane(projectLayeredPane);

    JPanel projectMenu1 = new JPanel();
    projectLayeredPane.setLayer(projectMenu1, 0);

    final JButton startNow = new JButton();
    startNow.setText("Exit");
    startNow.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
                {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
        });



    projectFrame.add(projectLayeredPane);
    projectLayeredPane.add(projectMenu1);
    projectMenu1.add(startNow);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should ideally make FlashcardGUI extend JFrame

Comment: @cricket_007 Personally, I wouldn't, I'd extend it from a `JPanel` at the most, it gives more flexibility, extendability and control over how the component is displayed

Comment: @MadProgrammer all depends on primary functionality, I suppose

Comment: @cricket_007 I'd argue against that, based on 16+ years of professional development in Swing/UI, the frame carries way more functionality, additional responsibility and locks you into a single use case - IMHO

Answer (score 2):

Put these two lines at the end of your main method. The order is important in order to make the button display.

```
projectFrame.pack();
projectFrame.setVisible(true);
```

(Make sure to remove the `projectFrame.setVisible(true);` you already have on line 9.)

Answer (score 2):

I have updated your code and it is working now. Please see the inline comments for the issue in your code. Hope this helps.

```
public class FlashcardGUI2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame projectFrame = new JFrame("StudyFast Flashcard");
    projectFrame.setName("StudyFast Flashcards");
    projectFrame.setSize(1000,600);
    projectFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    projectFrame.setVisible(true);
    JLayeredPane projectLayeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
    LayoutManager layout = new FlowLayout();   //creating a FlowLayout object
    projectLayeredPane.setLayout(layout);   //adding the layout to JLayeredPane
                                            //because JLayeredPane do not have default layout of
                                            //its own. The reason you were not 
                                            //getting the button displayed
    projectLayeredPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 310));
    JPanel projectMenu1 = new JPanel();
    final JButton startNow = new JButton();
    startNow.setText("Exit");
    startNow.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
        });
    projectLayeredPane.add(projectMenu1,new Integer(50));
    projectLayeredPane.add(startNow,new Integer(10));
    projectFrame.add(projectLayeredPane);
    projectFrame.pack();
    }
}
```